# multiple columns values in one column row Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got multiple columns value which need to display as below in the result area.
In colNum column I need to concatenate the value for each result
Kindly advise

Table name: test

| colNum | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 341 | 635 |
| 2 | 323 | 434 | 343 |

Result

| colNum | col123 |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1-U | 123 |
| 1-2-U | 341 |
| 1-3-U | 645 |
| 2-1-U | 323 |
| 2-2-U | 434 |
| 2-3-U | 343 |

when I try unpivot got below result but unable to concate the additional value in colNum

Result

| colNum | col123 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT` and concatenation:

```sql
SELECT colNum || '-' || col || '-U' AS colNum,
       col123
FROM   table_name
       UNPIVOT(
         col123 FOR col IN (col1 AS 1, col2 AS 2, col3 AS 3)
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (colNum, Col1, Col2, Col3) AS
SELECT 1, 123, 341, 635 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 323, 434, 343 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLNUM | COL123 |
| --- | --- |
| 1-1-U | 123 |
| 1-2-U | 341 |
| 1-3-U | 635 |
| 2-1-U | 323 |
| 2-2-U | 434 |
| 2-3-U | 343 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MiQ3yWh5)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but - to me it looks as union of 3 selects.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (colnum, col1, col2, col3) as
  2    (select 1, 'a', 'b', 'c' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'x', 'y', 'z' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select colnum ||'-1-U' colnum, col1 col123
  6  from test
  7  union all
  8  select colnum ||'-2-U' colnum, col2
  9  from test
 10  union all
 11  select colnum ||'-3-U' colnum, col3
 12  from test
 13  order by 1;

COLNUM     COL123
---------- ----------
1-1-U      a
1-2-U      b
1-3-U      c
2-1-U      x
2-2-U      y
2-3-U      z

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `UNPIVOT` clause :

```
SELECT colNum || '-' || col_code || '-U' as colNum, col123
FROM mytable
UNPIVOT(
    col123 
    FOR col_code
    IN (
        col1 AS '1', 
        col2 AS '2', 
        col3 AS '3'
    )
);
```

Result :

```
COLNUM  COL123
1-1-U   123
1-2-U   341
1-3-U   635
2-1-U   323
2-2-U   434
2-3-U   343
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SvJfMCTE)